# What is the induced voltage in the configuration of the image?

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

I have a subtle question regarding induced voltage in a system, where a a rotating rod is electrically connected by a sliding contact with a conductive ring, perpendicular to a homogeneous and constant magnetic field.

A Voltmeter is placed as shown in the figure.

[image: Rotating rod in constant homogeneous magnetic field]

Now the question:

I assume, that due to induction law

$$\oint (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B) = \frac{d \Phi}{d t} $$

The integration path does not necessarily go along a conducting wire and van be taken most generally.

E is the electric field in the laboratoy system, where the voltmeter is at rest.
B application of Lorentz Transformation, the electric field in a part, which is moving with velocity v relative to this laboratory system, is:

$$ \vec E' = \vec E + \vec v \times \vec B $$

E' must be zero in a system, where part of a moving wire is at rest, so, by integration along the conducting loop we get

$$\oint (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B) = \int_P^Q (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B) + U = \frac{d \Phi}{d t} $$

Since the way from P to Q is completely in a wire, we have

$$ U = \frac{d \Phi}{d t} $$

Since flux through the moving loop is changing by time (for instance flux through the loop for the dotted position b) is negative with regard to the other position a) we have an alternating voltage U on the voltmeter.

On the other hand, on could argue, that a shot radial element of the rod is moving with velocity $$ v = \omega r $$ giving rise to a field $$ \omega r B $$ which yields a constant voltage by integration

$$ U = \omega r^2 B /2$$

So from that rather naive approach there is a constant voltage, while the first approach gives an alternating voltage.

I prefer the first answer, but colleagues say, that the second is right...

EDIT-1:

In the left picture the surface is oriented clock-wise, as indicated by orange arrows. The B field is in the "same direction" (applying screwdrivers rule), so the flux is positive.

In the right picture the surface is oriented in the same way, but the B field is now in the "opposite direction" (again applying screwdrivers rule), so the flux is negative.

In the bottom picture the flux is even zero.

So flux through the loop is definitely changing. So, assuming induction law

$$ U = \frac{d \Phi}{d t} $$

is applicable, the voltage U cannot be constant.

[image]

Comment: Michael, you are right that your magnetic flux $\Phi$ changes sign. But what does not change sign is the negative time derivative $$\frac {d \Phi}{dt}= \frac {d [\Phi(t_a) - B \omega r^2 ( t-t_a)/2]}{dt} =-B r^2 \omega/2$$ Thus your induced voltage $U$ is constant and doesn't alternate!

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity: but if flux changes sign twice in a full a rotation (of course with regard to a given contour orientation), and you say that this is indeed the case, how can it then be have constant derivative ? Something that changes sign many times when time increases cannot be constantly increasing or decreasing. Again- sorry (?)

Comment: Michael, you cannot extend the surface integral beyond making a full turn of the angle ($2\pi$) to determine the  magnetic flux.

Comment: OK. Now I got it. It was my silly assumption, that the flux goes to zero at 180° and has its maximal value at 90°. That is nonsense, because flux increases until 180° and has discontinuous sign change then. There is no continuous zero passing at 180°. That was my problem.

Comment: Michael, I think that you are right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternating voltage induced on the voltmeter. Your application of the induction law is correct but you overlooked that in going from point a to point b there is also a sign change in the surface orientation of the surface integral because the integration sense of the line integral changes from clockwise to counterclockwise. Therefore the time derivative of the magnetic flux in the induction law doesn't change sign when the rod goes from point a to point b and you get a constant induced voltage $U$.

Comment: Are you sure? I really appreciate your answer, but see my edit and comments above: In the new image, for the top situations fluxes (as defined by the orientation of the contour) have different signs, whereas in the bottom situation flux is definitely zero (what else?). So Flux cannot be constant in that loop.

Comment: @michael - I have added an explanation in my comment to your EDIT 1 of your question.